# Nvidia driver for Debian

Tags: ubuntu, debian, nvidia

Is there a "real solution" or driver for Nvidia Optimus graphic cards? I tested a lot of alternatives but no success. I know a lot of users face the same problem with Debian or Ubuntu-family. [This solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48888/hopelessly-stuck-on-making-nvidia-driver-work-on-debian) does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/) (used to switch between the nVidia card and the integrated graphics when you have Optimus) should [work on Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) (just add the PPA and install the packages).

In Debian I didn't try, but [this repo](http://suwako.nomanga.net/) should work.

Comment: Debian instructions [there](https://wiki.debian.org/Bumblebee)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, Bumblebee just not working on my PC, maybe because I have HD graphics installed on my computer.