# Where did nvidia-driver go?

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia, gdm3

As far as I'm aware, all nvidia driver [installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48888/hopelessly-stuck-on-making-nvidia-driver-work-on-debian) [instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92243/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-on-debian-jessie) in Debian Jessie are the same as the [Debian Wheezy's](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers) and involve the instalation of `nvidia-kernel-dkms` and `nvidia-driver` packages. The problem is that both packages are [now gone](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/nvidia-driver). Can anyone provide updated driver installation instructions? I own a GeForce GTX 750, my current kernel is 3.14-1-amd64 and I'd like to keep using Debian's repositories since they (usually) are the most convenient way to keep drivers updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see from [this link](http://packages.debian.org/nvidia-driver) that it is in wheezy-backports and sid, but not jessie, as you say. The version in sid appears to be quite a bit higher than I remember a couple of weeks ago. Most packages move to jessie automatically after 5 days, I think, so you could either wait for a bit or install from sid. The old version could have been removed from Jessie due to a major bug or vulnerability or something, or the new version from sid had a critical bug causing it to be removed from jessie. The problem is, as it is non-free, Debian devs can't change it and must wait for NVIDIA to release a new driver.

Comment: Indeed, [it got broken](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//non-free/n/nvidia-graphics-drivers/nvidia-graphics-drivers_340.24-2_changelog) while [migrating to X 1.16](https://release.debian.org/transitions/html/xserver1.16.html).

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem, I suppose we don't have [nvidia legacy support](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=730745#10) in jessie. The packages disappeared after a recent upgrade.

Comment: We expect answers to be a bit more comprehensive here. Could you please expand, perhaps explain what the bug report says or provide a workaround?